# Calculations of the inverse matrix of $A + \alpha {\beta ^T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

Recently I have previewed something about  linear algebra. And I found an interesting problem. It can be viewed as a small general conclusion.
$A$ is an invertible matrix, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two n-dimensional column vectors. Then
$$1 + {\beta ^T}{A^{ - 1}}\alpha  \ne 0$$
How to Calculate  the inverse matrix of $$A + \alpha {\beta ^T}$$

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is essentially the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula.

Comment: @ VHarisop Thank you very much!